# RAM Warning R815 DELL

Tags: memory, dell-poweredge

I tried to set a R815 DELL server with 192GB capacity.
The problem is that when I turned on the server the following warning message appeared :
warning : the installed memory configuration is not optimal.
I have 16x8GB RAM model m393b1k70dh0-yk0 and 16x4GB model m393b5273dh0-yh9.
Both are Registered and compatible, so I don't know what's wrong with it...

Any help with that would be much appreciated !

Thanks

Yrian

Comment: Really? Even a cursory look at the memory section of the hardware manual would have given you the information you needed to answer your question. I applaud Chopper3's willingness to answer your question but I down voted your question for lack of effort on your part in solving your own problem.

Comment: joeqwerty -> You really think that I posted this before checking the manual ?
What is the point with your message except being aggressive ? It doesn't help at all. Chopper3 -> Thanks for your help. I already followed step by step the installation as it is written on the manual but I still have this warning. I just wanted to know if I had to worry about it and how it could be removed. Obviously, and as you said, I can't change my RAM format, but what is weird is that it matched 100% with the supported configuration.
Anyway, thank you for your help, i will try to do it once more step by step and

Answer (score 5):

First of all there's a difference between 'not optimal' and 'doesn't work' - it's really only a minor warning. But it is right, it's not currently in one of the supported configurations (see page 27 of [THIS](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/products/pedge/poweredge_r815_technical_guidebook.pdf)), that said it should still work just fine - just not...well, optimally ok.

On page 92 of the [OWNERS'S MANUAL](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Manuals/all-products/esuprt_ser_stor_net/esuprt_poweredge/poweredge-r815_Owner%27s%20Manual_en-us.pdf), the section "General Memory Module Installation Guidelines" discusses the best slots to use in what order and for what module. Obviously you can't magically turn your 8GB DIMMs into 16GB ones but if you do what you can to adhere to their guidelines then at least you've done your best - it should work fine either way. If you're in any further doubt just run [MEMTEST+](http://www.memtest.org/) on the machine for a day or so, it gives the memory a real workout and will show up any faults pretty quickly.